# Django project not in virtual environtment folder?

Tags: django, virtualenv

I was cloning django project, then i try to run the project that next step is to install virtual environtment.

I was confusing because usually project is in the virtual environtment folder(see the pic) but it is not, althought the project run properly.

Anybody can explain?

This is my project layout

[image: 1]

Comment: This is ok because we never commit the environment files as they are very big in size, so we can keep the environment folder anywhere but before running the project just activate that environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is OK. Look at screen from my project:

[image]